# SmartGWT and IE11 support

Tags: internet-explorer, smartgwt, internet-explorer-11

Has anybody experienced the pleasure of IE11 and SmartGWT?

IE 11 introduces a new User Agent string which seems to cause lots of UI issues in our SmartGWT application. If you take a look at SmartGWT's showcase (http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#main) you will see what I'm talking about.

Changing IE11 to compatability mode (adding your site to the compatability list) seemed to help with their showcase, but still saw too many problems in our app to suggest that to our customers.

Comment: Your question may not lead to a satisfying result as it can be answerde with yes or no.

Comment: Turned out that SmartGWT had already supported IE11 for a while. We just had to upgrade to the latest SmartGWT 4.1d build and our app was back in business.